# Setting MXG macro variable &SMFEXIT to CICS globally

Tags: sas

z/OS 1.11, MXG 32.10, SAS 9.3, Batch

I'm working on upgrading MXG to 32.10 with SAS 9.3.  While running a CICS report today, I received the message that MXG was taking 20x to 30x CPU processing to decompress messages because the decompression exit was not enabled.  To do so, I have to set the macro variable &SMFEXIT to CICS in each run, as follows (I had already assembled and linked the exit and had it available in STEPLIB):

```
%LET SMFEXIT=CICS
```

Other options are available but they are more complex and still need set every time I want to access the CICS data.  I used it in my program and it worked fine and ran much, much faster.

I figured I'd put this into AUTOEXEC.  It didn't work there.  AUTOEXEC seemed to process normally with no errors, meaning there was no output at all...  It may have had a warning, but that wouldn't show.  Only errors display from AUTOEXEC.

I found that I could specify global option ECHOAUTO, along with SOURCE, to display AUTOEXEC processing.  That has to be done either in CONFIG or as an invocation parameter.  I tried both options and neither worked.  I purposefully misspelled it in CONFIG and that threw an error, so I know it was being found.  SAS lists the invocation parameters in SASLOG, so ECHOAUTO and SOURCE were both listed there.  I received no indication that those options were working and AUTOEXEC processing just didn't go to SASLOG.

I ran PROC OPTIONS RESTRICT and nothing was restricted.

All the messages kept telling me to talk to the System Administrator.  I found nothing that told me who that was, what they were supposed to do or how to find out...  I sit by our System Administrator and he was no help with this because I'm the one that knows SAS.  Or, I thought I did...

So, how do I set &SMFEXIT to CICS globally?  Bonus for information as to why ECHOAUTO totally ignored me and information about the System Administrator.  Also, where can I find information about the limitations of AUTOEXEC as in what can or cannot be there.  Better yet, tell me in what guide I can find this information myself.  I searched for a long time and couldn't find any of that.  SAS documents are many.  SAS information about these questions is either scarce or just impossible to find.

Thanks...

**UPDATE:** I am considering setting up my MXG proc so that it has a concatenation that throws in this control card ahead of the MXG/SAS programs.  Seems like an awful hack...  Still would like other options and answers to the ancillary issues IAAP.  Thanks again.

Comment: As far as limitations to autoexec - there are no restrictions as to what sas code can exist in your autoexec file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah yes, the head slap...  Every issue above is easily explained by the fact that AUTOEXEC is not being called!  Variables aren't set.  Logic isn't added to the SASLOG.

We use Windows SAS, too.  We use AUTOEXEC.SAS to extensively initialize that environment.  On the other hand, on z/OS, we use JCL and parameters to initialize SAS without using AUTOEXEC, so it has never been implemented.

On z/OS, the AUTOEXEC global option defaults to the SASEXEC ddname.  I added the appropriate JCL to my MXG PROC to point to my AUTOEXEC member.  Voila.  My variable is set.  The logic is available in SASLOG.  Everything appears to be working, all with one simple root cause.

Thanks...